# New water simulation for 2.8 not showing up

Tags: fluid-simulation

I wanted to do a water simulation in a cube, but for some reason the water particles only show up for a couple of frames before disappearing completely. If you have any suggestions, please let me know.[image]

Comment: check the number of frames of the simulation on the DOMAIN properties. the default is 40 (so the simulations stops very early)

Comment: Okay so that works now, but after my newly set frame time, it disappears when it plays over the frames after that. How do I make the liquid stay and ripple?

Comment: add more simulation frames..